# Gravitation - Is going beyond a model possible?

Tags: gravity

I can not really understand why two bodies attract each other, what happens between? One points out the **gravitational field** to explain this phenomenon  and one say that it is because of the **general relativity**. I am aware that these both are just models and that this is how humans do when it comes explaining phenomena. However, I'd like to ask that which model is more *real*? Are there any experimental conclusion on what happens between two bodies (e.g., between Sun & Earth)?

Sorry, if the question is silly.